# Using javascript, can onsubmit="return selection()" be added to form?

Tags: javascript

how can I add a onsubmit="return selection()" function to a form using javascript?

Please see here: [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/u8zhhxpL/1/)

```
id="product_configure_form"
```

Comment: Go with `JavaScript-Event-Binding` and use `event.preventDefault()` instead of approaching `onsubmit="return selection()"`

Comment: What do you mean "add it to a form using javascript"?  Can't you just type that code into the `form` element?  What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks! How would that look Rayon? If I may ask, could you please update the JSFIDDLE?

Answer (score 0):

> Go with `JavaScript-Event-Binding` and use `event.preventDefault()` instead of approaching `onsubmit="return selection()"`

```js
$('#product_configure_form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Form submission is prevented..');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="add-to-cart clearfix" action="http://www.photographycoursetour.com/cart/add/46111438/" id="product_configure_form" method="post">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```